# CSS transition hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the element (`"block1"`) to stay fixed on hover.

I read that this might be possible using javascript. But I couldn't make it work.

Here's my code.

```css
#block1 {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: 2s;
}

#block1:hover {
  height: 800px;
}

body {
  font: 20px/1.1em arial, sans-serif;
  background: lightgray;
}

#container1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #f0dcbe;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#container2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#block2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #c80000;
  bottom: 60px;
}

#line1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 270px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: 20% 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
    <div id="line1"></div>
    <div id="line2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nav9xyhr/

Comment: What do you mean by _"stay fixed"_? Please explain what you would like to happen?

Comment: please try to explain more?

Comment: Do you want to height of the `#block1` will be 800px even when the mouse pointer leaves the element?

Comment: Yes. I want it to stay expanded after hovering.

Comment: you can use z-index to overlap the div

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener on mouseover to block1 and give the fixed height(800px in your case) for block1.

```
var  block1 = document.getElementById('block1');
block1.addEventListener('mouseover', animateBox);
function animateBox(){
    block1.style.height = '800px';
}
```

updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nav9xyhr/4/

Comment: Thank you! Though, I can't make it work. Where do I have to place the javascript?

Comment: you can place your javascript inside the script tag before closing the body tag.

<body>
.....
.....
<script>
.......
</script>
</body>

This is not recommended when you have more javascript. I can suggest creating a new app.js file and include that file in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `z-index` if you want to overlap it over the red block.

Try this

```css
body{
  font:20px/1.1em arial, sans-serif;
  background:lightgray;
}

#container1{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 600px; 
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #f0dcbe;
 z-index: 0;
 position: relative;
}

#container2 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
 height: 800px;
 top: 100px;
 left: 100px;
 z-index:2;

}

#block1 {
 display: block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-transition: 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
 transition: 2s;
  z-index:1;
}

#block1:hover {
 height: 800px;
}

#block2 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #c80000;
 bottom:60px;
  z-index:-1;
}

#line1 {
 position:absolute;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 width: 400px;
 height: 1px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 bottom: 270px;
 transform: rotate(-10deg);
 transform-origin: 20% 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>constructivism</title>
    <!--
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <meta property="og:title" content="constructivism" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="constructivism" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="" />
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
  <div id="container1">
  
   <div id="container2">
   
    <div id="block1"></div>
        
    <div id="block2"></div>
    
    <div id="line1"></div>
        
        <div id="line2"></div>
       
   </div>
    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the white block to stay expanded after hovering (which I gathered from the comments) then here is a trick in pure CSS that comes very close.

```css
#block1 {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;       /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: 2147483s;         /* very slow transition */
}

#block1:hover {
  height: 800px;
  transition: 2s;
}

body {
  font: 20px/1.1em arial, sans-serif;
  background: lightgray;
}

#container1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #f0dcbe;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#container2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#block2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #c80000;
  bottom: 60px;
}

#line1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 270px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: 20% 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
    <div id="line1"></div>
    <div id="line2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to slow down the transition from large to small to an almost imperceptible rate (2147483648ms, or three and a half weeks) so that it looks as if nothing happens.
It's not perfect, but you won't need JavaScript.

Let me know if this was what you were after; I may have got your intentions wrong.

Comment: That's what I was after. Thank you.

Comment: OK. Then can you edit the question and add this requirement in? That will make it easier for future visitors to find this problem (and its solution).